# How to 'output' in different div via JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, jsp

Im new on javascript. Im coding a JSP which is creating a product catalog from database source including a dropdown, inside each product, in order to display different options per product. The issue is I cannot handle output for each element, with this code the output is being displayed only in the first element. Im assuming I need to update the output div, no clue how to do it. Thank you for the help in advance.

**HTML**

```
<%<c:forEach var="phone" items="${listPhone}">%>
    <div class="product">
        <span class="box-price">USD ${phone.price1}</span>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <select class='phone_plan'>
            <option>${phone.price2}</option>
            <option>${phone.price3}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<%</c:forEach>%>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".phone_plan").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=value;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: that `<div id="output"></div>` will create multiple divs with the same id - which is not valid HTML, and you can see why - `this` in the event handler will have a `.previousElementSibling` which will be the "output" that you are looking for ... so `this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (since you already using jQuery) you can chain [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `output` `<div>` tag, note that in my snippet, I changed it to be a class attribute not `id`, since it will make the HTML invalid to have multiple element with the same `id` attribute, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".phone_plan").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find(".output").html(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="product">
        <span class="box-price">USD ${phone.price1}</span>
        <div class="output"></div>
        <select class='phone_plan'>
            <option>${phone.price2}</option>
            <option>${phone.price3}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="product">
        <span class="box-price">USD ${phone.price1}</span>
        <div class="output"></div>
        <select class='phone_plan'>
            <option>${phone.price2}</option>
            <option>${phone.price3}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div class="product">
        <span class="box-price">USD ${phone.price1}</span>
        <div class="output"></div>
        <select class='phone_plan'>
            <option>${phone.price2}</option>
            <option>${phone.price3}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        <hr />
    <div class="product">
        <span class="box-price">USD ${phone.price1}</span>
        <div class="output"></div>
        <select class='phone_plan'>
            <option>${phone.price2}</option>
            <option>${phone.price3}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I updated the question with JQuery, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad to help :)